# Line graphs overlap in JavaScript used with Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am using Google Chart JS lib for chart display with Django. I am sending the data to be shown in the graph as an array by packing it piece by piece in python. Everything is fine, including the processing of the data. But while it normally needs to plot 3 different graphs, it uses the data of 3 graphs in all 3 graphs and overlaps them.

My Code:

```
{% for graph_index in 1|custom_range:all_graph_data %}
    var graphId = 'curve_' + '{{ graph_index }}'
    var data_{{ graph_index }} = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data_{{ graph_index }}.addColumn('number', 'Time');
    data_{{ graph_index }}.addColumn('number', 'Current');
    data_{{ graph_index }}.addColumn('number', 'Voltage');

    {% for graph_values in all_graph_data|index:graph_index %}
        data_{{ graph_index }}.addRow([{{ graph_values|index:2 }}, {{ graph_values|index:0 }}, {{ graph_values|index:1 }}]);
    {% endfor %}


    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(graphId));
    chart.draw(data_{{ graph_index }}, options);
{% endfor %}


// add graph
{% for graph_index in 1|custom_range:all_graph_data %}
    <div class="container" id="curve_{{ graph_index }}"></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Normally a graph should look like this: https://prnt.sc/nEQv6-eTk1lw
[Normally a graph should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY3FV.png)

But my graph:https://prnt.sc/gOaN_08yDulN
[But my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq5tB.jpg)

**Version:**

- Python: 3.9.0
- Django: 4.2.2

I sent my data packaged in several different ways. Same problem.